# magento, long response from server

Tags: magento-1.9

I can’t understand why there is a very long response from the server. Everything can work well for 2-3 days, and then, by some magical case, the site starts loading for a long time. I'm doing a restart mysql , but it does not help restarted php-fpm, also nothing.I did many more different things, but it doesn’t work. Only full server restart helps.

How can I understand why the long answer is

Comment: you need to look at processes, check `mytop`, cpu load, i/o load, error logs,  do not restart anything. like cron issues, reindex, etc